# Given an array and positive integer d, left shift the array by d efficiently

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, rotation, shift

This is the **HackerRank** problem description:
A left rotation operation on an array of size n shifts each of the array's elements d unit to the left. For example, if left rotations are performed on array [1,2,3,4,5], then the array would become [3,4,5,1,2].

Here is my function :

```js
function leftRotation(arr, d) {
    let newArr = [];
    while (d > 0) {
        let first = arr.shift();
        newArr.push(first);
        d--;
    }
    return [...arr,...newArr];
}

console.log(leftRotation([1,2,3,4,5], 2))
```

but it doesn't pass large test cases. For example, for `n=73000` and `d=60000`.

Thanks in advance for any idea .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure the performance of this method, but it can be done in a single line.

```js
function leftRotation(arr, d) {
    return [ ...arr.slice(d), ...arr.slice(0, d) ];
}

console.log(leftRotation([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rotate N number of times. Shift `N % (length of array)` times, because Let's say you have an array of `5` items and you are asked to shift it 5 times then you essentially do not have to shift even once.

```
Start : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
2: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
3: [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
4: [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**EDIT:**

You could use similar logic to optimize the code instead of `actually shifting` elements in the array. For example: In case of `N = 73000, D = 60000`, you could `splice` the array by `73000 % 60000` and then just append the returned spliced array to the existing array and return it.

Comment: thanks for ur help. i tried it, it doesnt work for large test cases

Answer (score 0):

- For an array `arr` a method `shift()` can have a time complexity of `O(arr.length)`.
- If `d` is larger than `n` then you still perform `shift()` `d` times.
- In total, your time complexity can rise to `O(d * arr.length)` that is definitely too long.

However, this problem can be solved in `O(arr.length)` time and space. If you know `d` then you can shift each item by `d` positions to the left easily. For instance, `arr.length = 5` and `d = 2`

```
position:        0 1 2 3 4
     arr:        4 3 5 1 6              

position in arr: 2 3 4 0 1  
shifted_arr:     5 1 6 4 3
```

So actually, each item at position `i` in the shifted array corresponds to an item at position `(i + d) % arr.length` in the original array `arr`. Hence, the code can look as follows:

```js
function leftShift(arr, d) {
    let newArr = [];
    let size = arr.length;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArr.push(arr[(i + d) % size]);
    }
    
    return newArr;
}

console.log(leftShift([4, 3, 5, 1, 6], 2))
```